# Binding the text of a TextField to some object (JavaFX)

Tags: java, textfield, onchange, javafx-8

I have been struggling for now one hour to perform a very basic thing. Indeed, I have a class called `Template` that holds a `Map<String,String>` :

```
public class Template extends AbstractLateXElement {
    protected final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    // many unrelevant code
}
```

I then have a class called `TemplateForm` that is a JavaFX form constructed by taking a `Template` as a parameter. It creates one field for each key of the map and set the associated value. I would like any change done in the textfields to change the relevant pair in the map accordingly. I know I could use `textProperty().bind()` but I would like to keep by `Template` class totally JavaFX-independent.

I can think about some wrapper class that would wrap my map and provide binding methods, but what I would prefer here is a simple change listener to define. However, after diving into the documentation I found nothing that worked :

- I tried defining the `onInputMethodTextChanged` property but my listener was never fired
- I tried setting the value using `TextField.getText` in an `onKeyTyped` method, but the returned by `getText` is not always synchronized with the value displayed in the field
- I found the `TextInputControl.Content` class that would be perfect for me but is protected etc).

What is the best way to do what I want without needing to modify `Template` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was kind of stupid... The listener have to be added to the `textProperty`, resulting in an obvious code (in `TemplateForm`) :

```
// t is an instance of Template
final Map<String,String>           params = t.getParameters();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> it     = params.entrySet().iterator();

Map.Entry<String,String> param;
int i;
for (i=0, param = it.hasNext() ? it.next() : null ; param != null ; i++, param = it.hasNext() ? it.next() : null) {
    Label     label = new Label();
    TextField field = new TextField(param.getValue());

    final String key = param.getKey();
    field.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> obs, String oldValue, String newValue) -> params.put(key,newValue));
    // unrelevant code
}
```